# How do you publish tests/artifacts in Azure DevOps (VSTS)

Tags: azure-devops, teamcity, vstest, azure-artifacts

In Team City, tests are updated as they pass or fail which is useful for long running tests (you might abort the run).

You can also publish arificts while the build is running. e.g.

```
##teamcity[publishArtifacts 'alogOrScreenshot']
```

Can you do this in Azure DevOps, ideally using the VS Runner?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Azure DevOps has support for in-progress view of Test data as soon as its published instead of awaiting completion of session. More details @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/review-continuous-test-results-after-build?view=azure-devops#view-execution-of-in-progress-tests.

To add, Junit / Xunit / NUnit and Ctest formats are supported with Publish test results task. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: Has anyone got this working in Build with the VSTestAdapter?